# Getting sublist in Java

Tags: java, list, sublist

In Java, i want to get subList from a list. i cannot use subList of java as i want sub list based on some valus in list.

I have List of DTO objects. DTO is like

```
MyClass myClass;
int hit;
```

And MyClass  is like

```
String webName;
...
```

I want to get sublists which has same webName (i need to add total hits of webName and remove dupicate DTO objects which has same webName )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question, what you have now is

```
List<MyDTO> dtos;
```

and you want to get to

```
List<List<MyDTO>> sublists;
```

So just iterate over your dto's, find the correct entry in a map, and add the hits to the container.  The map will make sure you have only one entry per webname.

```
Map<String, List<MyDTO>> hitmap = new HashMap<String, List<MyDTO>>();

for (MyDTO dto: dtos){
  String webname = dto.getMyClass().getWebName();
  List<MyDTO> list = hitmap.get(webname);
  if (list==null){
    list = new ArrayList<MyDTO>();
    hitmap.put(webname, list);
  }
  list.add(dto);
}
```

Then, if you really just want the bunch of sublists, just get it from the values

```
List<List<MyDTO>> sublists = new ArrayList<List<MyDTO>>(hitmap.values());
```

Comment: i don't want map. i need list only. i need to return same list object to calling methods. i cannnot modify as i have to use other's code.

Comment: Adapted the answer to return sublists. If this is not what you require, adapt your question to explicitly name the type you need.

Comment: The list/map only contains references to your DTOs. They are the same DTO instances.

Comment: webname could be duplicate in my case. so if i call put for Map  will it not replace earlier object ? in example code it is hitmap.put(webname, list);

Comment: No, because it first tried to get the list with that webname.  If it were already in the map, it would've gotten the existing list.  In other words, this code only executes the `put` call, if the webname isn't in the map yet.

Comment: but in my list webname is not unique. it code be webName "abc" hit 10, webname "xyz" hit 12 and webname "abc" hit 15. and i required list which has webname "abc" hit 25, webname "xyz" hit 12.

Answer (score 0):

How about ?

*To hold list of DTOs which has same name*

```
Map<String, List<YourDTO> > mapNameToDtos
```

or even better

*to hold just count which has same name*

```
Map<String, Integer > mapNameToCount
```